# Loop until correct answer is given

Tags: loops

Hi could some one please help. I am very new to Python and need help with something I am creating. I would like to to print six statements and then ask the user to enter their answer. The answer needs to be ie. S2, S10 etc. etc. If not true would like it to loop again until correct input has been given.

Please see below:

```
print("S0 = Initail Issue ")
print("S2 = Information Issue ")
print("S3 = Internal Review & Comment Issue ")
print("S4 = Suitable for Construction in DPP Stage only ")
print("S10 = Construction Issue")
print("CR = Construction Record (As Built)Issue\n")
Initial = "S0"
Information = "S2"
Review = "S3"
DPP = "S4"
Construction = "S10"
As_built = "CR"

Suitability = (input("Look above on the list of suitability is it?\n ").upper())
Suit = {"Initial", "Information", "Review", "DPP", "Construction", "As_built"}
while True:
    Suit = Suitability
    if Suit == Suitability:
        break
    else:
        print("is not the correct information! ")

    Suitability = (input("Look above on the list of suitability is it?\n ").upper())
```

Comment: What help do you need?  Is something not working as you expected?  Are you having trouble moving forward?  From reading your post, I get no feeling as to what you do or do not understand about the problem, Python, or even programming in general.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi Wyck, The issue I have is a can enter any letters and it will accept the input. What I would like it do is only accept S0,S2,S4,S10 or CR. If those are met will like it move on. If not re-ask the question until the answer is met. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("S0 = Initial Issue ")
print("S2 = Information Issue ")
print("S3 = Internal Review & Comment Issue ")
print("S4 = Suitable for Construction in DPP Stage only ")
print("S10 = Construction Issue")
print("CR = Construction Record (As Built) Issue\n")
Initial = "S0"
Information = "S2"
Review = "S3"
DPP = "S4"
Construction = "S10"
As_built = "CR"

validOptions = [Initial, Information, Review, DPP, Construction, As_built]

while True:
    Suitability = (input("Look above on the list of suitability is it?\n ").upper())
    if Suitability in validOptions:
        break
    print("is not the correct information!")

print("You entered", Suitability)
```

I used `if`  ***`item`***  `in`  ***`container`*** syntax to validate the input by checking to see if the provided input is in a list of valid options.

I also restructured your loop so that you only have to express the `input` prompt once in your code.

Comment: _Disclaimer:  I am not a Python programmer!_

Comment: Thanks Wyck, Works perfectly and make sense now